# MySQL select all table data, gouped by one column data

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
serial|vehicule|alert_emails
12411|AAA|yes
12411|BBB|yes
13411|CCC|yes
13411|DDD|yes
14411|EEE|yes
```

I want to do a mysql query to select all data and organize it by serial field to get a array result like this:

```
12411
   AAA|yes
   BBB|yes
13411
   CCC|yes
   DDD|yes
14411
   EEE|yes
```

I tried group by the field serial but I'm not getting the desired result:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable GROUP BY serial;
```

Any help please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` to get the distinct `serial`s of the table and all the rows of the table:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.col IS NULL THEN t.serial END serial, t.col
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT serial, null AS col
  FROM mytable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT serial, CONCAT(vehicule, '|', alert_emails)
  FROM mytable
) t  
ORDER BY t.serial, t.col IS NULL DESC
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b6f76aaff8dab86925d8d6650b9a48ff).